# Number node list is wrong with xpath java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<fields>
    <field>
        <name>ID</name>
        <shortcode>id</shortcode>
        <display>true</display>
        <table_id>1</table_id>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>Name</name>
        <shortcode>name</shortcode>
        <display>true</display>
        <table_id>1</table_id>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>ID</name>
        <shortcode>id</shortcode>
        <display>true</display>
        <table_id>2</table_id>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>Name</name>
        <shortcode>name</shortcode>
        <display>true</display>
        <table_id>2</table_id>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>ID</name>
        <shortcode>id</shortcode>
        <display>true</display>
        <table_id>3</table_id>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>Name</name>
        <shortcode>name</shortcode>
        <display>true</display>
        <table_id>3</table_id>
    </field>
</fields>
```

I want to get all "field" element that have table_id=1 (or 2, 3,..). I tried code below but it's wrong:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forgot this
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(filePath);

XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("fields/field[table_id=1]");

Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    //System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getChildNodes().item(i).getTextContent());
    NodeList childNodes = nodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
        System.out.println(childNodes.item(j).getTextContent());
    }
    System.out.println(childNodes.getLength()); // **why 9 nodes**
}
```

I don't know why is it 9? The result as I want is 4 node. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child *nodes* includes text nodes - the element

```
<field>
    <name>ID</name>
    <shortcode>id</shortcode>
    <display>true</display>
    <table_id>1</table_id>
</field>
```

does indeed have nine child nodes, consisting of the four child element nodes plus the five whitespace text nodes between the `<field>` and `<name>`, `</table_id>` and `</field>`, and between the closing tag of one child element and the opening tag of the next one.

If you only care about child *elements* rather than child *nodes* then you should filter for only those child nodes that are `instanceof Element`, or alternatively you could extract just elements with another XPath expression

```
XPathExpression childEltsExpr = xpath.compile("*");
```

and then in the `for` loop

```
NodeList childElements = (NodeList)childEltsExpr.evaluate(nodes.item(i),
      XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: How do I repair my code to get all text node? Example: ID - id - true - 1

Comment: Sorry! I mean I want to filter with condition like that fields/field[table_id=1]?

Comment: @user3331563 I'm not sure I understand.  The initial `nodes` list will already contain that filtered list (the results of the first XPath, i.e. the first two `field` element nodes).  Your outer `for` iterates over that list, and within there you can extract whatever you need using either more XPath expressions or the standard DOM APIs (e.g. `((Element)nodes.item(i)).getElementsByTagNameNS(null, "name")`)

Answer (score 0):

Because you also have text nodes (spaces between tags). You should try to select only children that are element node. eg with node.getNodeType()